# What cassete do I need to run with a compact crankset (50/36), to equal the same gearing as running a standard crankset (53/39) with a 11-28 cassete?

Tags: gears, cassette, crankset

Every new bike in my price range comes with a compact crankset, which I want for climbing, but I race and I need to keep the same top speed that I've had for sprinting and descending (I live in the mountains). So I'm just wondering what rear cassette I would need to use with my compact cranks to equal the same gearing as using a normal crankset (53/39) with a 11-28 cassete.

Comment: That's a bit unusual for a compact crankset... Sure you don't mean 50/34?

Comment: You could just swap a mid-compact crankset on the new bike running 53/36 or 52/36 chainrings. This is an option for Shimano 105, Specialized S-Works and other brands. It wouldn't be super cheap with race level components.  Adjust the rear cassette size to get the range you need for climbing.

Comment: @freiheit not so unusual, I'm using one from sram.

Answer (score 4):

**It's not possible. You'd gain lower gears, but lose your very highest gear.** If you want to keep that highest gear, maybe you should look at a wider-range cassette to get there, instead?

If you were switching from a 53/39,12-28 setup to a 50/34,11-28 setup, it would work out well.

Switching your largest chainring from 53 to 50 basically shifts all your high gears about 1 notch lower.

11 teeth is the smallest cog you can get on a road bike cassette, currently. I've seen BMX bikes with a smaller gear on the back, but they're not cassette based.

You can compare gear ratios on a given bike (where wheel diameter, tire width and crank length can all be assumed to be a constant with simple division.

Assuming your 11-28 is 11-12-13-14-15-17-19-21-24-28, or similar:

```
53:11 = 4.8
53:12 = 4.4
53:13 = 4.1
...
39:21 = 1.9
39:24 = 1.6
39:28 = 1.4   

50:11 = 4.5
50:12 = 4.2
50:13 = 3.8
...
36:21 = 1.7
36:24 = 1.5
36:28 = 1.3
... or if it's the more common 50/34:
34:21 = 1.6
34:24 = 1.4
34:28 = 1.2
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [bikecalc](http://www.bikecalc.com/) to calculate the ratios or gear inches for yourself.  Then you can figure out range equivalent setups for any combination of chainrings / cogs.

Comment: Keep in mind, you'll never get as fast of a ratio using a crankset with a 50t big ring vs a 53t big ring. You just can't get a rear cog any smaller than a 11 tooth on standard 9 or 10 speed cassette that will  match the 53x11 since your fastest possible combination will be 50x11.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are interested in top speed I assume that means you really want to replicate the 53/11 combo. One way of finding a similar combination is by looking at a ratio of the front and back gear.

A 53/11 gear ratio will give you a gain of 4.81.
A 50/11 gear ratio will give you a gain of 4.54.

To recover the .27 difference you would need to run a 10.4 (or 10) tooth top gear.

Comment: I don't think I've seen too many 10 tooth cassettes.  It would probably be too small to fit on the freehub body.  50/11 is faster than 53/12, so you're right it's only that very bottom gear that matters. I think that you really have to analyze how often you are in the 53/11 gear, and if you're really maxing out the RPMs in that gear. I think you could probably go just as fast in both gears, you'd just need to spin slightly faster.

Comment: I've never seen a ten tooth either. That wasn't really the question though. Figuring out speed, gear inches, and anything else is really a trivial exercise for excess detail.

Answer (score 0):

11-26.

You can't get higher gear combination than 53/11 with a 50, 11 is the smallest cog available.
And 53/28 is about equal to 50/26. Hopefully it will be more comfortable because the tighter gear ratios.

Comment: The Shimano Capreo system goes down to a 9 tooth cog, but it only works with the Capreo hub, and it's designed for small wheeled bikes like folders, not normal road bikes. http://sheldonbrown.com/capreo/index.html
cf. http://www.pinkbike.com/news/9-36-cassette-prototype-2011.html (9 tooth MTB cog, prototype only), http://www.moultonbicycles.co.uk/images/models/Pdfs/Moulton%20Hubs%20and%20Sprockets.pdf (Moulton hub with 10 tooth cog).